# filter Google Analytics API pagepath to not show further subdirectories

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm looking to do a top ten list of the main pages of a bio but not the additional subdirectories. E.g.

```
/cr/johndoe
/cr/janesmith
```

but NOT:

```
/cr/johndoe/news
/cr/janesmith/dvds
/cr/santaclaus/galleries/1
etc.
```

I've started with `filters=ga:pagePath==/cr/*` but I'm not sure how to do the regex to get it to not go any deeper.

Comment: Try `filters=ga:pagePath=~/cr/[^/]*/?$`. Or Url-encoded: `filters=ga:pagePath%3D~%2Fcr%2F%5B%5E%2F%5D*%2F%3F%24`. If the URL starts with `/cr`, add `^`: `filters=ga:pagePath=~^/cr/[^/]*/?$` (or Url-encoded `filters=ga:pagePath%3D~%5E%2Fcr%2F%5B%5E%2F%5D*%2F%3F%24`).

Comment: Posted, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match the `/cr/something` you can use the following filters:

```
filters=ga:pagePath=~/cr/[^/]*/?$
```

Or Url-encoded version:

```
filters=ga:pagePath%3D~%2Fcr%2F%5B%5E%2F%5D*%2F%3F%24
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `/cr/` - matches the sequence of the characters literally
- `[^/]*` - 0 or more characters other than `/`
- `/?` - 0 or 1 `/` symbol
- `$` - matches the end of string.

If the URL starts with `/cr`, add `^` (start of string):

```
filters=ga:pagePath=~^/cr/[^/]*/?$
```

or Url-encoded:

```
filters=ga:pagePath%3D~%5E%2Fcr%2F%5B%5E%2F%5D*%2F%3F%24
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
^\/cr\/\w+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gQ0zB6/1)